# Which version of Talos uses Tensorflow 1.12?

Tags: python, tensorflow, talos

I am trying to install Talos on my University's computing servers, however I get an error since the version of Talos I am trying to install (version 0.6.6) relies on Tensorflow 1.14, which I do not have access to. The modules provided by my University's server, only provide Tensorflow 1.12, so I want to figure out which version of Talos I need to install to make it compatible.

Comment: What error do you see, and what method are you using to install? In general, you can usually find compatible versions between python packages by using pip install or conda install.

Comment: I am using pip install, but I can't seem to find some list of which Talos versions utilize which Tensorflow versions. My error was diagnozed by the High-Performance-Computing support team at my Uni, so I do not have an error message per se.

Comment: I put my response in an answer for better readability

Answer (score 0):

Version 0.1.9 seems to be compatible, at least it does not generate any package conflict errors when i run this command:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.12 talos==0.1.9
```

Make sure your support team includes this

```
tensorflow==1.12
```

in the install command, otherwise pip will try to update to a more recent version of tensorflow and possibly other packages, by default.

Other versions may also be compatible, you can test those other version using this same method.

Complete list of versions can be found here:

https://pypi.org/project/talos/#history